# Sound over telnet?

Tags: audio, telnet

I'm making a console based game over telnet.

It would be nice to play a few sound bytes!

Is the best thing available the bel char?

Comment: You should use SSH with X-Window instead of Telnet I guess.

Comment: SSH is nice if there is anything secure being transfered, a game might be "insecure" without trouble. X is help for GUI applications, but itself won't solve the sound issue.

Comment: there is `\a` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a (standard) way to directly stream audio data through telnet. People have tried to do so with [extensions to the protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD_client#Telnet_extensions), though.

Another approach that I've seen used (for example in IRC) is to have the clients recognise a special command that says "please play this audio file". The client would look in a configured directory for an audio file by that name, and if found then it would play the sound. Depending on your needs, this could be a workable technique.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Telnet gives only a character stream, no higher level features.